# using .eq(3) instead of .next().next().next()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, Anybody can show me how to use this one line of code. 
Wide explanation would be great - why this is not working

I want to change this

```
selected= $(this);
      selected = selected.next().next().next().next();
```

To this

```
var selected = $('div');
    selected = $(this);
    selected.eq(4).fadeTo(220,1);
```

but this one doesn't want to work.
example is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raVyRw  //here I have code where I used next() like 100 times!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What do you get? How does what you get deviate from what you expect? How does the HTML that you select look like?

Comment: Your examples do not make sense. `$('body').find(this)` just returns `this`. Might as well just use `$(this)`.

Comment: Look at the docs on http://api.jquery.com/find/ which provides you with example. Use $(this)

Comment: @Sari: Perhaps you can make it a little clearer what the thrust of your question is. Currently it is not at all clear. The question should contain all necessary detail with the link to the external resource just being a bonus. As it is I can't make any sense of what you are after from reading the question (Alex Char's answer giving me more insight into what you are after than the question).

Answer (score 3):

I create a css class with opacity and using [**mouseenter**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [**mouseleave**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events with [**addClass**](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [**removeClass**](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) ended up to this:

```js
$("div").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
  //e.type describes the nature of the event.
  if (e.type == "mouseenter")
    //add class on mouseenter
    $(this).addClass('withOpacity');
  else
    //remove class on mouseleave
    $(this).removeClass('withOpacity');
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.withOpacity {
  opacity: 0.4
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
```

Same result using [**hover**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$("div").hover(function(e){
   $(this).toggleClass('withOpacity');
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.withOpacity {
  opacity: 0.4
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
</body>
```

Comment: I will admit the question is a bit confusing and I'm not sure I understand it fully but isn't it about the use of `.eq` or `.next`, that's certainly what the title suggests but I don't see these in your code anywhere...

Comment: @Chris If you check OP codepen will realise that tries to make something simple a bit complicated :)

Comment: This is a fair point you are making, but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: Allright guys, obviusly we are not in the same phase. The point was if u go ahead and check out my example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raVyRw where it has //bottom & //top codeblock. I'm using .next() method to reach 10nth element. I need to amend it somehow using eq()

Comment: @Sari can you explain why you create something so complicated? I mean what is the point? Can't get what you try to achieve..

Comment: Did u try to click any buttons? Well its just a beginning I'm going to build up ten more like this with switch  case and then return random case which lights up different anytime u click it. I mean this amazing.

Comment: ok so you want to go at the element user clicks all the way to the end(up down left right)?